# "Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined" when using Google Chrome (*googlechrome) as Selenium RC target

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run a test in Google Chrome 9.0.597.98 beta using Selenium Grid.  I'm firing the test off from C# using the default *googlechrome target that ships with Selenium Grid.  When I try to open a site, I'm greeted with a **"Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined"** error.

I've found a post from someone who suggests that the solution is to drop security on Chrome a bit by passing in some parameters.  [This post](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/msg/360750753ca98b69?pli=1) suggest using something like this:

`DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(location, port, browser, targetPath);`

`BrowserConfigurationOptions bco = new BrowserConfigurationOptions();`

`selenium.start(bco.setCommandLineFlags("--disable-web-security"));`

For some reason I don't see the `BrowserConfigurationOptions` anywhere.  **Is this something that ships with the Selenium dll?  Is it something that's not available in the .NET version, but is in others?  What options do I have to setting this "--disable-web-security" option and is there a** better way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[TestInitialize]

public void PreTest()
{
 selenium = new    DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"googlechrome","http://www.ryanhayes.net")
}


[TestMethod]

public void TestRyanHayesDotNet()
{
selenium.Open("/")

}
```

removing the / after the ryanhayes.net fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for this, I was looking this information and I got it here!
Now I'm able to run my test in googlechrome, earlier I was getting the same problem.

Following code is working for me:

```
BrowserConfigurationOptions webSec = new BrowserConfigurationOptions();
selenium.start(webSec.setCommandLineFlags("--disable-web-security"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in assuming .Net doesn't have `BrowserConfigurationOptions` object, but fortunately you don't need it (it's only a thin wrapper). DefaultSelenium has two overrides for the `Start()` method. One of them takes no parameters and starts the browser normally, but the other takes a string specifying browser options. try `selenium.Start("--disable-web-security")`

Comment: Doesn't look like there's an overload for Start for me.  I'm running v1.1.4322 of the ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll.  Is there a different one that I need somewhere that contains the overload?

Comment: Found it.  I downloaded the Selenium RC version originally, which only had .Start().  I just now got the Selenium WebDriver version, which contains the updated Thoughtworks.Selenium.Core.dll.  I added the disable web security option, but I still get the same error message.  Must be something else.  :-/

Comment: In C# DefaultSelenium, not ISelenium has the Start with options overload. However, it does not work as advertised. I can avoid the error message by ensuring that all of my work is done on the same domain. In your example, everything would be in http://www.ryanhayes.net